# BootCamp: error occurred while partitioning disk. Disk Utility's First Aid says volume is OK

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I'm trying to set up a Win10 partition on my late 2013 rMBP through Boot Camp Assistant, however I'm getting stuck on partitioning:

[image]

Then after heading to Disk Utility, I try using the First Aid option and everything turns out fine:

[image]

Then I try doing a partition via Disk Utility:

[image]

However I get operation failed due to the disk size being too small:

[image]

I have no idea why this isn't working. I'll try to provide as much information as possible, so here is `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            180.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             70.7 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +179.6 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 B191F8EE-7EE7-40DF-8711-274537FC4103
                                 Unencrypted
```

Comment: Your Recovery  HD (disk0s3) should not be 70.7 GB. There are other users you may be able to fix this problem. I can suggest downloading and reinstalling the version of OS X (MacOS) you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson, took 3 hours to restore from time machine backup but everything works!